# Using quotation mark in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, opencart

I have a list of 1000 products I am currently importing into OpenCart. Some of the product titles contains an quotation mark to symbolise the inches (for example 5").

I have imported all of these products successfully using this query:

```
$data['name'] = mysql_escape_string($data['name']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".DB_PREFIX."product-description SET language_id = '1', name = '".$data['name']."'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
```

When I am in OpenCart the list of products also show proberly however when I go to edit the product the title input field (which is meant to show the title) cuts out the title from the " symbol onwards.

Here is a visual example:
[image]

Here we see the title is complete
[image]

Here we see the title as been cut out after the ".

I can confirm it is not an OpenCart coding error because if I manually insert products from the interface with a " it works fine. The error must lie within my query.

If there is a problem with my query, is there a query where I can update all the products rather than re-insert them?

Comment: "Explanation marks" are not a thing. They're *quotation* marks.

Comment: another reason to switch to metric.

Comment: The [mysql_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php) function has been deprecated in PHP 5.3.0. You should use the [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) function instead.

Comment: I am not using PHP 5.3.0, and I would rather not update at this moment in time.  And @meagar for the correction,  I can't beleive I got the two mixed up!

Comment: have you confirmed that `$data['name']` contains the correct stuff before using it in the query?

Comment: Yeah, I ran an echo $data['name']; and it shows it as it should.

Comment: `echo $sql` and post the actual query.

Comment: Can you perform a SELECT against the database for a row you inserted through your import script, and a separate one for a row you inserted through OpenCart's interface, to see if the quotation marks are there in both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know insides of OpenChart, but this symptom is quite clear and common:

> **Here we see the title as been cut out after the ".**

This usually means the content is passed to HTML without doing proper HTML escaping first. For example, you got INPUT like this:

```
<input type="text" value="#VAL#" />
```

`#VAL#` is a placeholder, being replaced with the value when needed. But when your value is i.e. `Tablet 7" No Name` then your HTML would end looking like this:

```
<input type="text" value="Tablet 7" No Name" />
```

which clearly explains why it is being cut after first `"`. The solution is to use said **escaping**, (or using more proper names - convert special characters into **entities**), which in case of HTML can be handled in PHP with `htmlspecialchars()` function, so your SQL query got nothing to do with it - it's just a matter of incorrectly handling dealing with HTML markup.

When entities are dealt correctly, above example would look (in source) like this:

```
<input type="text" value="Tablet 7&quot; No Name" />
```

which then makes no troubles to the browser (and the browser will additionally show " entity correctly as `"`).

More on `htmlspecialchars()` and in general special chars in HTML [is here](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

Comment: This may be the problem! I didn't even think of that! What I don't understand is when I use theinterface to insert products its fine when I go to the edit page.  When I use my direct query it doesn't like it.. anyways, i will give it a try.

Comment: Thanks,  that was bang on!  I forgot to mark this as answered!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

openCart is designed so that it escapes all HTML in any data it's going to store in the DB **before** it stores it. So you just have to modify:

```
$data['name'] = mysql_escape_string($data['name']);
```

to:

```
$data['name'] = mysql_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($data['name'], ENT_QUOTES));
```

Answer (score -3):

When you collect data from the form, just escape all quotation marks with a backslash `\`.
Replace all single quotes `'` with `\'`

Comment: That's what his line: `$data['name'] = mysql_escape_string($data['name']);` does.